# MySQL - return row number where value=3

Tags: mysql, where-clause, row-number

I want to use a MySQL query which returns all row numbers which are matching a certain value.

I do already have an attempt that is the following:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM `TABLE` t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

This returns all values which are stored inside the table "TABLE" with an additional column "rank" showing the row number.

So how do I adapt this code snippet to only get the "rank" column and how do I get a "where column1 = 3" query to that MySQL request?

Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: If I understood well, you are trying to select only the row with rank = 3, and you calculate the rank of each row at the moment of the execution of the query. Is it right?

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, sorry for being fuzzy...
I want to return the rank only where a value in a certain other column is 3...

Comment: The point is that the ranking that you're doing here is actually relying on an `ORDER BY` optimization done by MySQL, which is not guaranteed to remain constant in the future. In general, it isn't very safe to rank the rows of a table dynamically, in theory the ranking could be completely different every time you execute the query. See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: Sure I know that, but the table is ranked by date and time everytime a new row is added and I need the exact order of the data like I added them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a subquery and test for what you want in the main query.

```
SELECT rank
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
    FROM `TABLE` t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) AS x
WHERE column1 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

So how do I adapt this code snippet to only get the "rank" column:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM `TABLE` t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Comment: Thank you that worked regarding only returning the "rank" column!
So the only missing part is to get a condition to the query...

Comment: Aren't you inventing a very complicated way to do LIMIT 3,1? If not, fine, but this might help you enormously if you are,

Comment: I don't think so, because I want to know the row number which LIMIT does not return and I want to have all values which are 3, but not only 3 values.